# Clock Configuration for Atmel ASF USB CDC Device (Virtual COM)

Tags: c, usb, device, atmel, cdc

I am implementing a USB CDC device function on a custom board with Atmel SAML21 micro-processor. As ASF library already provided users with its built-in USB CDC methods, what I need to do is modifying the source code accordingly to make it compatible with my board. However, my biggest concern is that the board does not have an external 32kHz oscillator (SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_XOSC32K), which is used as a reference clock source for closed-loop DFLL to generate 48 MHz USB peripheral clock. I used the 32kHz internal clock (SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC32K) instead and modify the content of conf_clock.h as follows:

```
#include <clock.h>

#  ifndef CONF_CLOCKS_H_INCLUDED
#  define CONF_CLOCKS_H_INCLUDED

/* System clock bus configuration */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_CPU_CLOCK_FAILURE_DETECT     false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_FLASH_WAIT_STATES            2
#  define CONF_CLOCK_CPU_DIVIDER                  SYSTEM_MAIN_CLOCK_DIV_1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_LOW_POWER_DIVIDER            SYSTEM_MAIN_CLOCK_DIV_1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_BACKUP_DIVIDER               SYSTEM_MAIN_CLOCK_DIV_1

/* SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC16M configuration - Internal 16MHz oscillator */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC16M_FREQ_SEL              SYSTEM_OSC16M_16M 
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC16M_ON_DEMAND             true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC16M_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false

/* SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_XOSC configuration - External clock/oscillator */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC_ENABLE                  false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC_EXTERNAL_CRYSTAL        SYSTEM_CLOCK_EXTERNAL_CRYSTAL
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC_EXTERNAL_FREQUENCY      12000000UL
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC_STARTUP_TIME            SYSTEM_XOSC_STARTUP_32768
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC_AUTO_GAIN_CONTROL       true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC_ON_DEMAND               true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC_RUN_IN_STANDBY          false

/* SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_XOSC32K configuration - External 32KHz crystal/clock oscillator */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC32K_ENABLE               false /* previously was true */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC32K_EXTERNAL_CRYSTAL     SYSTEM_CLOCK_EXTERNAL_CRYSTAL
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC32K_STARTUP_TIME         SYSTEM_XOSC32K_STARTUP_65536
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC32K_ENABLE_1KHZ_OUPUT    false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC32K_ENABLE_32KHZ_OUTPUT  true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC32K_ON_DEMAND            false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_XOSC32K_RUN_IN_STANDBY       true

/* SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC32K configuration - Internal 32KHz oscillator */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC32K_ENABLE                true /* previously was false */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC32K_STARTUP_TIME          SYSTEM_OSC32K_STARTUP_130
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC32K_ENABLE_1KHZ_OUTPUT    false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC32K_ENABLE_32KHZ_OUTPUT   true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC32K_ON_DEMAND             true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_OSC32K_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false

/* SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSCULP32K configuration - Internal Ultra Low Power 32KHz oscillator */

/* SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_DFLL configuration - Digital Frequency Locked Loop */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_ENABLE                  true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_LOOP_MODE               SYSTEM_CLOCK_DFLL_LOOP_MODE_CLOSED
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_ON_DEMAND               false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_RUN_IN_STANDBY          false

/* DFLL open loop mode configuration */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_FINE_VALUE              (512)

/* DFLL closed loop mode configuration */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_SOURCE_GCLK_GENERATOR   GCLK_GENERATOR_1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_MULTIPLY_FACTOR         (48000000/32768)
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_QUICK_LOCK              true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_TRACK_AFTER_FINE_LOCK   true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_KEEP_LOCK_ON_WAKEUP     true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_ENABLE_CHILL_CYCLE      true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_MAX_COARSE_STEP_SIZE    (0x1f / 8)
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DFLL_MAX_FINE_STEP_SIZE      (0xff / 8)

/* SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_DPLL configuration - Digital Phase-Locked Loop */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_ENABLE                  false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_ON_DEMAND               true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_RUN_IN_STANDBY          false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_LOCK_BYPASS             false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_WAKE_UP_FAST            false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_LOW_POWER_ENABLE        false

#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_LOCK_TIME               SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_DPLL_LOCK_TIME_DEFAULT
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_REFERENCE_CLOCK         SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_DPLL_REFERENCE_CLOCK_XOSC32K 
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_FILTER                  SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_DPLL_FILTER_DEFAULT
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_PRESCALER               SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_DPLL_DIV_1


#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_REFERENCE_FREQUENCY     32768
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_REFERENCE_DIVIDER       1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_OUTPUT_FREQUENCY        48000000

/* DPLL GCLK reference configuration */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_REFERENCE_GCLK_GENERATOR GCLK_GENERATOR_1
/* DPLL GCLK lock timer configuration */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_DPLL_LOCK_GCLK_GENERATOR     GCLK_GENERATOR_1


/* Set this to true to configure the GCLK when running clocks_init. If set to
 * false, none of the GCLK generators will be configured in clocks_init(). */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_CONFIGURE_GCLK               true

/* Configure GCLK generator 0 (Main Clock) */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_0_ENABLE                true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_0_RUN_IN_STANDBY        true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_0_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_DFLL
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_0_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_0_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false

/* Configure GCLK generator 1 */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_1_ENABLE                true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_1_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_1_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC32K /* Previously was SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_XOSC32K */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_1_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_1_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false

/* Configure GCLK generator 2  */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_2_ENABLE                false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_2_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_2_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC16M
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_2_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_2_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false

/* Configure GCLK generator 3 */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_3_ENABLE                true
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_3_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_3_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_DFLL
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_3_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_3_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false

/* Configure GCLK generator 4 */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_4_ENABLE                false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_4_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_4_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC16M
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_4_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_4_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false

/* Configure GCLK generator 5 */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_ENABLE                false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC16M
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_5_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false

/* Configure GCLK generator 6 */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_6_ENABLE                false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_6_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_6_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC16M
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_6_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_6_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false

/* Configure GCLK generator 7 */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_7_ENABLE                false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_7_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_7_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC16M
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_7_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_7_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false

/* Configure GCLK generator 8 */
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_8_ENABLE                false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_8_RUN_IN_STANDBY        false
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_8_CLOCK_SOURCE          SYSTEM_CLOCK_SOURCE_OSC16M
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_8_PRESCALER             1
#  define CONF_CLOCK_GCLK_8_OUTPUT_ENABLE         false
#endif /* CONF_CLOCKS_H_INCLUDED */
```

This modification did not result in any errors during compilation and run phase. However, udi_cdc_putc('A') which used to send an A character via USB CDC Virtual COM does not seem to work. I could not observe any character received at the host side (PC). Similarly, no character is received from the host side (PC) to the device side (Atmel SAM).

I thought that there may be two main cause for this Virtual COM failure:

- Improper clock configuration
- Improper installation of Atmel USB CDC driver on Windows 10.

Please let me know your opinions and give me ideas on how to fix this.

Thanks a lot and look forward to hearing from the community soon.

Comment: Seems like baud rate issue!!

Comment: The baud rate is left default, 115200, 8 bit data, no parity, 1 stop bit. This information could be found in conf_usb.h of ASF lib. I also set these parameters on Window terminal, but nothing was received.

Comment: DSO is your friend now, you have to check for activity on TX and RX pin. Or try connecting a LED (with serial resistor) and see if LED blinks (make sure to have some delay between consecutive byte transmitt.)

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I also think about using DSO to check whether the generated clocks are correct or not.